# How to add an R package (already in CRAN) to CRAN Task View?

Tags: r, r-package, cran

Let say I have an R package which is already published in [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/). I would like to add the same in a specific [CRAN task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/).

A few leads I already gathered are given in the **reference**.

But I'm not sure whether

- I can do it myself. (Whether there is a criterion for putting any packages in CRAN task views. Who maintains it. Whom to contact.)
- I can decide the section to add.
- I can add a new section altogether

#### Reference

- [ctv](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ctv/vignettes/ctv-howto.pdf) package
- [These Github](https://github.com/search?q=CRAN%20task%20view) repos. Example [ropensci/webservices](https://github.com/ropensci/webservices)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From CRAN Task View's main [page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/):

> The task views are maintained by volunteers. You can help them by suggesting packages that should be included in their task views. The contact e-mail addresses are listed on the individual task view pages.

Contact the maintainer. For example, for [Bayesian Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Bayesian.html).

> CRAN Task View: Bayesian
>   Inference Maintainer: Jong Hee Park
>   Contact:  jongheepark at snu.ac.kr